# .htaccess, double redirection evaluating uri

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this url structure:

```
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/index.php
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/index.php/welcome
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/index.php/blog
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/admin.php
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/admin.php/welcome
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/admin.php/dashboard
```

For `index.php` urls, I would like to keep this format:

```
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/    //default index view
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/welcome
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/blog
```

So, my .htaccess looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The .htaccess code above works fine. The problem resides for `admin.php` urls, because I want the urls format like (keeping the 'admin' word):

```
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/admin
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/admin/dashboard
proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/admin/welcome
```

Then, I have editted my htaccess like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  #RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^admin/(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin.php/$1 [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But when I browse `proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/admin` I get a 500 error, so I suppose that my rule for admin file is not working good enought.

### Logs

I have reviewed the `error_log`, and each time I try to acesss `proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/admin` it prints a message:

> Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.

Followed by a list of redirections:

```
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [error] [client 201.192.30.254] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 201.192.30.254] r->uri = /index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/admin
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/admin
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/admin
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/admin
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/admin
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/admin
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/admin
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/proyectos/index.php/proyectos/index.php/admin
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/proyectos/index.php/admin
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /index.php/admin
[Wed Dec 05 09:47:07 2012] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 201.192.30.254] redirected from r->uri = /ci-doctrine/admin
```

### Directory structure

For troubleshooting porpuses, below you can find my dir structure

```
public_html/
    .htaccess/
    index.php
    proyectos/
        ci-doctrine/
            .htaccess
            index.php
            admin.php
```

### Document root .htaccess

In the root, I have another installation of my application like in the subdomain `proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine` does, for this reason I am applying the same rule for `index.php` for urls.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

## UPDATE > working code

Well, with the help of @anubhava I got this work:

Document root .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Subdomain .htaccess:

```
# If the user types "index.php" or "admin.php".
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|admin\.php|images|robots\.txt)

# If the user types just "admin".
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin$ admin\.php [L,QSA]

# If the user enter in any admin section, like "admin/section".
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin\/(.*)$ admin\.php/$1 [L,QSA]

# If the user types any site section, like "site/section".
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is one extra (and incorrect) RewriteCond in your first rule. Here is the modified and correct code that should work for you:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin.php/$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

**EDIT:** Your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` should be modified like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?rootdomain\.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: As I mencioned below, the `example.com/admin` is taken as `example.com/index.php/admin` and it shows a 500 error with your htaccess

Comment: btw this is fully tested code in my web server. Now logically speaking if `admin.php` does exist in `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` then first rule will make it `/admin.php/plugin` and then 2nd rule will NOT fire because of `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` condition (since admin.php is a valid file).

Comment: I have the htaccess exactly like yours and looks like is something affecting it. I have edited the post for more details

Comment: I could put all the redirections that error_logs prints, but the urls changes because I am not using `example.com`. But I could post them if is necessary.

Comment: If that is your latest `.htaccess` then you still have an extra `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^admin/(.*)$ [NC]` line which needs to be removed.

Comment: I am sure that now the .htaccess file is ok, but could a parent htaccess affect the behaviour of its child?

Comment: Ah now that you have posted your directory structure, I need to know above .htaccess is directly under `$DOCUMENT_ROOT` or not? If not then do post your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` as well.

Comment: Ok that explains, why your were getting unexpected results since your `$DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` was putting `/index.php/` before every URI. Try out my edited answer now.

Comment: haha well... No more redirections! but, when I access a url like `proyectos.example.com/ci-doctrine/admin` I get:  `File does not exist: /public_html/proyectos/ci-doctrine/admin`. But now it is enought, the htaccess is fixed, because the error now looks like is in the app. Thank you for your help and time.. I really apreaciate it so much friend.   :)

Comment: You're most welcome, glad that I could be of any help to you.

Comment: Finally we got it :) Look the changes made at subdomain .htaccess, just added some rules and 100% working! Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^admin/(.*)$ /admin.php/$1 [L] 

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Same result: 500 error. I think that "/admin" is taken as URI of index.php